# How can I schedule jobs on different time in Gitlab

Tags: variables, continuous-integration, gitlab, scheduled-tasks

I have build and test jobs in Gitlab CI yaml.
I want to trigger build job every evening at 16.00
and I want to trigger test jobs every morning 4.00 on GitLab
and I know on Gitlab CI/CD - Schedules - New Schedule
but I don't know how can I write this and works in Gitlab CI yaml
I have uploaded my Gitlab CI yaml file. 
Can you show me please?

```
variables:
  MSBUILD_PATH: 'C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\Bin\msbuild.exe'
  SOLUTION_PATH: 'Source/NewProject.sln'


stages:
  - build
  - test

build_job:
  stage: build
  script:
    - '& "$env:MSBUILD_PATH" "$env:SOLUTION_PATH" /nologo /t:Rebuild /p:Configuration=Debug'
    - pwd
  artifacts:
    paths:
     -  'Output'

test_job:
  stage: test
  only:
    - schedules
  script:
    - 'Output\bin\Debug\NewProject.exe'
```

Comment: Why can't you run tests every time after build?

Answer (score 1):

Did you try [only:variables/except:variables](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#onlyvariablesexceptvariables)?
First you need to set proper variable in your schedule then add `only variables` to your yml config. Example:

```yaml
...
build_job:
...
  only:
    variables:
      - $SCHEDULED_BUILD == "True"

test_job:
...
  only:
    variables:
      - $SCHEDULED_TEST == "True"
```

If you always want to have 12 hours of delay you could use just one schedule and add [when:delayed](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#whendelayed)

```yaml
  when: delayed
  start_in: 12 hours
```

UPDATE: As per request in comments added complete example of simple pipeline configuration, job **build** should run when `SCHEDULED_BUILD` is set to `True` and **test** job should run when `SCHEDULED_TEST` is set to `True`:

```yaml
build:
    script:
      - echo only build
    only:
      variables:
        - $SCHEDULED_BUILD == "True"

test:
    script:
      - echo only test
    only:
      variables:
        - $SCHEDULED_TEST == "True"
```

Comment: how can I set proper variable in my schedule.Actually I dont know about  what I should enter "Input Variable" and "Input Variable Key" in gitlab UI Could you help me?

Comment: `Input variable key` `SCHEDULED_BUILD` and `Input variable` `True`

Comment: should I write input variable key SCHEDULED_BUILD and Input Variable False

Comment: I would create 2 schedules. 1st with `SCHEDULED_BUILD` `True` and second with `SCHEDULED_TEST` `True`

Comment: gitlab ci yaml gave error.If it's possible can you send me yaml file with variables.

Comment: I know it's possibly a bit hard. but its important for me

Comment: I prepared the schedule like you said but I run one of them. System said successfully but when I look CI CD pipelines I saw failed file

Comment: Do you mean `invalid yml`? You can always validate your gitlab-ci.yml file on page `<your gitlab project url>-/ci/lint`

Comment: no I know it. yaml look valid in CI lint. but jobs not started

Comment: I updated the answer with complete working example of yml file.

Comment: Note that you archive `output` in build step which is used later in test job. If you schedule only test without build step then you will have to deal with taking artifacts from other place.

Comment: actually I search how to do that :) I'm new in ci cd sorry for that? if you know how to do it? I need it works together with except schedules in build job

Comment: As I wrote in original answer, you could use `when: delayed` with 12 hours delay. But still this whole concept of delaying tests after build seems like a wrong idea. I don't know actual point of your jobs but there shouldn't be such a time gap between build and test steps.

Comment: I found: for build job take except the scheduled build. and for test job take only the scheduled build and scheduled test. It works. thank you very much